# An array as a parameter of a function in 8086 assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, stack, push, x86-16

I want to pass an array of bytes (or the pointer to that array) to a function in 8086 assembly.

When I try to `PUSH` that pointer, it gives me a compilation error. The error is "Wrong parameters".

```
org 100h

JMP Start  

Donnee DB 0ABh,0CDh,0EFh  

;; Principal program ;;
Start:

PUSH Donnee

CALL CalculeCRC  

POP CRC 

ret
```

Comment: As I'm sure you understand, it's quite helpful to include the actual error message you get when you try to assemble this program, too.

Comment: The message is error is not really helpful. Still, I've edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PUSH opcode expects a DWORD value, either in memory or a register. In your case, you're trying to push an array of three bytes. I think, technically speaking, this is valid code, but the assembler recognizes that it's not really want you intended. (It might be interested to see if the code will assemble if you added another element to your array of bytes, but that's beside the point).

In any case, what you are trying to do is not what you want to happen. You want to push the pointer to the array onto the stack before you call your function, you ARE NOT trying to push the entire array onto the stack. Even if the assembler let you this would be very bad because it would be a waste of memory. In order to do what you want to do, you'll need to get the address of your array and push that onto the stack. You can use LEA to get the "effective address" of the array:

```
lea eax, Donnee
push eax
```

of you can do the following:

```
push  OFFSET Donnee
```

Comment: Note that PUSH immed requires 80186 or higher (or compatibles like the NEC V20).  Was not available in the original 8086 instruction set.

Answer (score 0):

I'm certainly no expert in 8086, but I would read up on the PUSH instruction to see that it really can do what you expect.

From a very quick check, I think that it requires a register, so you need to first load the address into a register, then push the register.

Perhaps something like this:

```
lea  ax, Donnee
push ax
```

There might be punctuation and/or argument ordering errors here; I don't have an 8086 assembler handy.

Comment: That worked, thanks. The problem was not that PUSH needed a register, but that it was pusshing the 8 bit value to the stack and that the stack need a 16 bits value. Using LEA allow to find the 16 bits address of the array.